# Div inside a grid cannot have max height set by parent

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a html view where scrolling only occurs inside the bottom-right area of the view.

When the view becomes too big for the div with class `test-page-content` to fit (the yellow area), the div with class `page-content-area` (blue area) should show scroll bars.

But for some reason the height of the div with class `page-with-left-area` becomes too large and the whole view starts scrolling.

I found a workaround (see comment in `app-container` class), but that requires a fixed size for the header, which is not what I want.

The view should look like this:
[image: soll]

But the view looks like this (scroll bars on full view):
[image: ist]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>PageContainer</title>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .app-container {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
            /* WORKAROUND: Replace grid-template-rows with these two lines: */
            /*grid-template-columns: 100vw;
            grid-template-rows: 8.5rem calc(100vh - 8.5rem);*/
        }
        .page-with-left-area {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 18rem 1fr;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .page-content-area {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            padding: 0.5rem;
            padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
            background-color: blue;
            border: 3px solid black;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .test-header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 8.5rem;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .test-page-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            min-width: 40rem;
            min-height: 40rem;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app-container">
        <div class="test-header"></div>
        <div class="page-with-left-area">
            <div></div>
            <div class="page-content-area">
                <div class="test-page-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is needed to set `overflow:hidden` on parent tag `.page-content-area`.

Ater that, there is `bottom & right` padding ignore issue on `.page-content-area` and have resolved it to set the margins on child component.

Attached snippet resolves both problems.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>PageContainer</title>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .app-container {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
            /* WORKAROUND: Replace grid-template-rows with these two lines: */
            /*grid-template-columns: 100vw;
            grid-template-rows: 8.5rem calc(100vh - 8.5rem);*/
        }
        .page-with-left-area {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 18rem 1fr;
            background-color: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .page-content-area {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
            border: 3px solid black;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .test-header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 8.5rem;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .test-page-content {
            width: calc(100% - 1rem);
            height: calc(100% - 1.7rem);
            min-width: 40rem;
            min-height: 40rem;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 3px solid red;
            
            margin: 0.5rem;
            margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app-container">
        <div class="test-header"></div>
        <div class="page-with-left-area">
            <div></div>
            <div class="page-content-area">
                <div class="test-page-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Derek.W! Setting overflow:hidden solves the problem. Setting the margins solves the ignored padding when the scroll bars are needed, but it also adds scroll bars when they are NOT needed. Any solution for that?

Comment: Can you tell me more about that? Where the scrollbar appears?

Comment: When the view is full screen and there is enough room to show 100% of test-page-content (more than 40rem) there should not be scroll bars, but they appear because of the margin.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can resolve this problem by updating `width` and `height` attribute without margins.